# DocuSign REST API not creating Supplemental Documents

Tags: docusignapi

Attempting to use the REST API Envelope Create to include Supplemental Documents in the envelope [no templates], so with the first object in the Documents array having a display value of ‘inline’ and the signerMustAcknowledge set to  ‘null’ we have for the second object in the array used the display value of ‘modal’ and the signerMustAcknowledge set to ‘no_interaction’ or to ‘view’.  When the recipient reviews the envelop online the supplemental document is not shown as grey strip below the primary document offering the reviewer any options, instead the document is expanded and shown in full. What other options do we need to set to get DocuSign to treat the second document as supplemental, as described in https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-send-supplements.

Spoke to DocuSign Support yesterday to get the ‘Supplemental Documents’ functionality added to our Demo Account and the Permission Set on the User being used for this REST API connection has the ‘Disable document upload’ unchecked and the Allow supplemental documents option (and all related options below) is checked.

Example anonymised JSON:

```
{
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "routingOrder": 1,
        "recipientId": "1",
        "name": "Person-A",
        "email": "person-a@website.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emailSubject": "Test subject",
  "emailBlurb": "Test blurb",
  "documents": [
    {
      "signerMustAcknowledge": null,
      "order": "asc",
      "name": "MyCompany Quote",
      "includeInDownload": null,
      "documentId": "1",
      "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp/Og0M……",
      "display": "inline"
    },
    {
      "signerMustAcknowledge": "no_interaction",``
      "order": "asc",
      "name": "MyCompany Quote",
      "includeInDownload": false,
      "documentId": "2",
      "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMiAw……",
      "display": "modal"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code or payload?

Comment: Original edited to include the JSON.

Comment: You are not assigning any DocuSign tabs to the signer? your documents part of JSON is correct, just not assigning tabs might be creating an issue. If you don't assign tabs then it is called free form signing which is not allowed in most of the plans and might not work for supplemental docs. Try by assigning atleast one tab to signer in the non-supplemental document

Comment: @AmitKBist you should post this as an answer, the lack of tabs is what is causing the issue.

Comment: @Andrew Done, please accept my answer

Comment: @amitKBist not my question, but I'll upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning any DocuSign tabs to the signer? your documents part of JSON is correct, just not assigning tabs might be creating an issue. If you don't assign tabs then it is called free form signing which is not allowed in most of the plans and might not work for supplemental docs. Try by assigning atleast one tab to signer in the non-supplemental document. Lack of tabs is causing the issue.